# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment SIGSEGV (0xb)

Tags: java, linux

I have searched and attempted many things as found on here and other forums, non seem to work, I have ruled out a Hardware issue.

If anyone could help, that would be great.

Thank you

Issue:

I am running a modded minecraft server, sometimes this doesn't happen and sometimes it will happen frequently. The server will just terminate with no word of warning and show this error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fd6f0bff5c2, pid=8009, tid=0x00007fd64d089700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# j  net.minecraft.nbt.NBTTagCompound.func_74734_a(Ljava/io/DataOutput;)V+30
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007fd6832d6000):  JavaThread "File IO Thread" [_thread_in_Java, id=8307, stack(0x00007fd64cf89000,0x00007fd64d08a000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x0000000800000028

Registers:
RAX=0x00000007c0001610, RBX=0x00000007fffffff8, RCX=0x0000000000000030, RDX=0x0000000564f926a8
RSP=0x00007fd64d088828, RBP=0x00007fd64d088868, RSI=0x00000000ffffffff, RDI=0x0000000000000001
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x00007fd648033580, R10=0x00007fd705f29360, R11=0x0000000000000000
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x00007fd6df8d872e, R14=0x00007fd64d088898, R15=0x00007fd6832d6000
RIP=0x00007fd6f0bff5c2, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007fd64d088828)
0x00007fd64d088828:   00007fd64d088828 00007fd6df8d872e
0x00007fd64d088838:   00007fd64d088898 00007fd6df9adb10
0x00007fd64d088848:   00007fd64de39ee8 00007fd6df8d87a0
0x00007fd64d088858:   0000000000000000 00007fd64d0888a0
0x00007fd64d088868:   00000000eb1999ba 00007fd6f3314e64
0x00007fd64d088878:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fd64d088888:   00000007601e3e38 000000075fbdf9e8
0x00007fd64d088898:   0000000758cccdd0 00000007c00af9a8
0x00007fd64d0888a8:   0000000758ccc500 000000075fbdf9e8
0x00007fd64d0888b8:   00007fd600000001 000000054af82930
0x00007fd64d0888c8:   00007fd6f2ee817c 000000075fbdfa08
0x00007fd64d0888d8:   000000075fbe2360 0000000758cf6a00
0x00007fd64d0888e8:   00007fd6f1e8fa84 0000000758ccb618
0x00007fd64d0888f8:   000000075fbdf9e8 000000075fbdf9e8
0x00007fd64d088908:   000000054af82930 0000000758ccc500
0x00007fd64d088918:   000000075fbdf9e8 0000000c5fbdf9e8
0x00007fd64d088928:   eb19ed4000000010 00000000eb1996c5
0x00007fd64d088938:   0000000758cf6a00 000000075fbdfa08
0x00007fd64d088948:   000000075fbe1ca8 0000000758ccb6a8
0x00007fd64d088958:   00007fd6f1e8fa84 0000000758ccb5d8
0x00007fd64d088968:   000000075fbdf9e8 000000075fbdf9e8
0x00007fd64d088978:   0000000540096e40 0000000758ccb618
0x00007fd64d088988:   000000075fbdf9e8 0000000a5fbdf9e8
0x00007fd64d088998:   eb1996d50000000b eb1ac873eb1996bd
0x00007fd64d0889a8:   0000000758ccb6a8 00000005403dfc30
0x00007fd64d0889b8:   0000000000000029 0000000000000001
0x00007fd64d0889c8:   00007fd6f3897350 0000000571c6a930
0x00007fd64d0889d8:   0000000000000007 eb1996bb00000000
0x00007fd64d0889e8:   000000075fbdf9e8 0000000578a47448
0x00007fd64d0889f8:   00007fd705f143f0 0000000000000031
0x00007fd64d088a08:   00007fd64d088a00 00007fd64d088ab8
0x00007fd64d088a18:   00007fd6f2a2c08c 0000000000000004 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007fd6f0bff5c2)
0x00007fd6f0bff5a2:   89 59 10 bf 01 00 00 00 48 89 79 18 48 83 c1 30
0x00007fd6f0bff5b2:   48 89 4d e0 48 3b d8 0f 84 5b 00 00 00 8b 48 0c
0x00007fd6f0bff5c2:   48 3b 04 0b 0f 84 4e 00 00 00 83 f9 18 0f 85 22
0x00007fd6f0bff5d2:   00 00 00 50 48 8b c0 57 48 8b 7b 20 8b 0f 48 83 

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x00000007c0001610 is pointing into metadata
RBX=0x00000007fffffff8 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000000030 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000564f926a8 is pointing into object: 0x0000000564ee5610
[B 
 - klass: {type array byte}
 - length: 1048576
RSP=0x00007fd64d088828 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fd6832d6000
RBP=0x00007fd64d088868 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fd6832d6000
RSI=0x00000000ffffffff is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R9 =0x00007fd648033580 is an unknown value
R10=0x00007fd705f29360: <offset 0xefe360> in /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el7_3.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so at 0x00007fd70502b000
R11=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x00007fd6df8d872e is pointing into metadata
R14=0x00007fd64d088898 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fd6832d6000
R15=0x00007fd6832d6000 is a thread


Stack: [0x00007fd64cf89000,0x00007fd64d08a000],  sp=0x00007fd64d088828,  free space=1022k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
j  net.minecraft.nbt.NBTTagCompound.func_74734_a(Ljava/io/DataOutput;)V+30
J 21333 C2 net.minecraft.nbt.NBTTagList.func_74734_a(Ljava/io/DataOutput;)V (104 bytes) @ 0x00007fd6f3314e64 [0x00007fd6f3314ba0+0x2c4]
J 15269 C2 net.minecraft.nbt.NBTTagCompound.func_74734_a(Ljava/io/DataOutput;)V (67 bytes) @ 0x00007fd6f1e8fa84 [0x00007fd6f1e8f5c0+0x4c4]
J 15269 C2 net.minecraft.nbt.NBTTagCompound.func_74734_a(Ljava/io/DataOutput;)V (67 bytes) @ 0x00007fd6f1e8fa84 [0x00007fd6f1e8f5c0+0x4c4]
J 22628 C2 net.minecraft.world.storage.ThreadedFileIOBase.func_75736_b()V (124 bytes) @ 0x00007fd6f3897350 [0x00007fd6f3896e20+0x530]
J 30302% C1 net.minecraft.world.storage.ThreadedFileIOBase.run()V (7 bytes) @ 0x00007fd6f2a2c08c [0x00007fd6f2a2c000+0x8c]
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x64153a]
V  [libjvm.so+0x63e9f4]
V  [libjvm.so+0x63f009]
V  [libjvm.so+0x682571]
V  [libjvm.so+0x9beee2]
V  [libjvm.so+0x871d22]
C  [libpthread.so.0+0x7dc5]  start_thread+0xc5
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [tag:minecraft] questions are off-topic unless they discuss the programming of a mod.